# Enum-like property design

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create the class equivalent of a Blockly Block in C#. [Here](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html)'s the official block creator for reference.

Now I'm trying to come up with the best way to design the Connections property for my object. It's kind of like an enum, but for certain values I need to also associate one or two types. Also, the connections are mutually exclusive so I cannot have a Left connection and a Top Connection at the same time for example.

```
public enum BlocklyConnectionType
{
    None, LeftOutput, Top, Bottom, TopAndBottom
}
public class BlocklyBlock : IBlocklyComponent
{
    public BlocklyConnectionType ConnectionType { get; set; }
}
```

If I do it this way then how can I set the types ? I'd have to add two properties to my BlocklyBlock class for that and I don't like that.

So the other way I thought of was making a new class for connections.

```
class BlocklyConnection
{
    public BlocklyConnectionType ConnectionType { get; set; }
    public BlocklyType ValueType { get; set; }
    public BlocklyType SecondValueType { get; set; }

    public BlocklyConnection(BlocklyConnectionType connectionType, BlocklyType valueType, BlocklyType valueType2 = null)
    {
        ConnectionType = connectionType;
        ValueType = valueType;
        SecondValueType = valueType2;
    }
}
```

I like this a bit more but it's still not perfect.

I also thought about removing the TopAndBottom option from the enum and then make some kind of bit flags for the rest of the options, but that probably only complicates things somewhat since I'd have to make a lot of extra checks for flag validity, and also doesn't solve my value association problem.

Comment: To me bit flags sound like a good option.